# which is best to save image in the photo library?

Tags: ios

I have came across two ideas of saving images from app to photo library.

1. `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(UIImage *image, id completionTarget, SEL completionSelector, void *contextInfo);`
2. `ALAssetsLibrary`

I used the first one but it takes more time to save. Which is fast way to save images in library?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` should be faster but anyway, you should and you have to do it on a background thread to not block the main thread and the UI.
Somehow like

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
   UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img.image, nil, nil, nil);
});
```

Comment: Yeah its not much fast.But it got better than previous.Thanks

Comment: I don't know what device you are trying but threading your app(s) should increase the performance a lot.

Comment: Im testing in iphone 5

Comment: Where does that image come from? Maybe processing the image also should be on a background thread. Also you could try monitoring the performance with Instruments to see what's taking up your CPU.

Comment: Its basically a very nice way to store images.

Comment: I use this code after capture image & didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo . I am getting null value.